# Basic Ticket booking code with Unit tests

Tags: java, object-oriented, unit-testing, junit, mocks

I am going to run a session for a few other developers who are new to Junit, mocking, etc.

I have designed a very simple application with classes and tests to demonstrate how to do unit testing. Please review the code and tests. Any suggestions are welcome.

The problem is of a sample booking service.

- `BookingService` talks to `PaymentGateway` and `TicketCenter`,
  returns different `BookingResponse`s based on input
- `PaymentGateway` takes booking amount and `Card`, charges the card as long as the card’s available limit is more than the booking amount.
- When booking amount exceeds the `Card`’s available limit, `Card` throws a cannot-charge exception
- `TicketCenter` can book tickets, as long as the booked tickets count hasn’t reached the limit when `TicketCenter` makes a booking, adds the booking to the list it maintains

### class Card

```
public class Card {
    private String provider;
    private double limit;

    public Card(String provider, double limit) {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void charge(double amount) throws CannotChargeException {
        if (this.limit < amount) {
            throw new CannotChargeException("low balance");
        }
        this.limit -= amount;
    }

    public double getAvailableLimit() {
        return limit;
    }
}
```

### class CannotChargeException

```
public class CannotChargeException extends Throwable {
    public CannotChargeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

### class CardTest

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class CardTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAvailableLimitAfterDeductionOfCumulativeCharges() throws CannotChargeException {
        Card card = new Card("Amex", 1000);

        card.charge(100);
        card.charge(100);

        assertEquals(800, card.getAvailableLimit());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenCardChargeExceedsLimit() {
        Card card = new Card("Amex", 1000);

        assertThrows(CannotChargeException.class, () -> {
            card.charge(1100);
        }, "low balance");
    }

}
```

### class Ticket

```
public class Ticket {
    private String user;

    public Ticket(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("This ticket belongs to %s", user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.user.equals(((Ticket) obj).user);
    }
}
```

### class TickerCenter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TicketCenter {
    private List<Ticket> tickets;
    private int limit;

    public TicketCenter(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
        this.tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected boolean canBook() {
        return this.tickets.size() < limit;
    }

    public Ticket book(String user) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(user);
        tickets.add(ticket);
        return ticket;
    }

}
```

### class TicketCenterTest

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class TicketCenterTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnFalseWhenTicketLimitReached() {
        String johnDoe = "John Doe";

        TicketCenter ticketCenter = new TicketCenter(1);
        ticketCenter.book(johnDoe);

        assertFalse(ticketCenter.canBook());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTrueWhenTicketLimitNotReached() {
        String johnDoe = "John Doe";
        String joeDoe = "Joe Doe";

        TicketCenter ticketCenter = new TicketCenter(3);
        ticketCenter.book(johnDoe);
        ticketCenter.book(joeDoe);

        assertTrue(ticketCenter.canBook());
    }

}
```

### class PaymentGateway

```
public class PaymentGateway {

    public void charge(Card card, double amount) throws CannotChargeException {
        card.charge(amount);
    }
}
```

### class PaymentGatewayTest

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class PaymentGatewayTest {

    private PaymentGateway paymentGateway;
    private Card card;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        card = mock(Card.class);
        paymentGateway = new PaymentGateway();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInvokeCardChargeMethodWhenPaymentGatewayChargeCalled() throws CannotChargeException {
        paymentGateway.charge(card, 100.00);

        verify(card, times(1)).charge(eq(100.00));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenCardThrowException() throws CannotChargeException {
        doThrow(new CannotChargeException("low charge")).when(card).charge(eq(100.00));

        assertThrows(CannotChargeException.class, () -> {
            paymentGateway.charge(card, 100.00);
        });
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBySpyCardAvailableLimitAfterPaymentGatewayCharge() throws CannotChargeException {
        Card amexCard = new Card("Amex", 1000);
        Card spyCard = Mockito.spy(amexCard);

        paymentGateway.charge(spyCard,100);

        assertEquals(900, spyCard.getAvailableLimit());
    }
}
```

### class BookingService

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class BookingService {

    private PaymentGateway paymentGateway;
    private TicketCenter ticketCenter;

    public BookingService(PaymentGateway paymentGateway, TicketCenter ticketCenter) {
        this.paymentGateway = paymentGateway;
        this.ticketCenter = ticketCenter;
    }

    public BookingResponse bookTicket(String user, Card card, double amount) {
        if (ticketCenter.canBook()) {
            try {
                paymentGateway.charge(card, amount);
            } catch (CannotChargeException e) {
                return new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.PAYMENT_ERROR, Optional.empty());
            }
            return new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.SUCCESS, Optional.of(ticketCenter.book(user)));
        }
        return new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.SOLD_OUT, Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

### enum BookingStatus

```
public enum BookingStatus {
    SOLD_OUT, PAYMENT_ERROR,SUCCESS;
}
```

### class BookingResponse

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class BookingResponse {
    private BookingStatus bookingStatus;
    private Optional<Ticket> ticket;

    public BookingResponse(BookingStatus bookingStatus, Optional<Ticket> ticket) {
        this.bookingStatus = bookingStatus;
        this.ticket = ticket;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        BookingResponse otherBookingResponse = (BookingResponse) obj;
        return otherBookingResponse.bookingStatus.equals(this.bookingStatus) && otherBookingResponse.ticket.equals(this.ticket);
    }
}
```

### class BookingServiceTest

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class BookingServiceTest {

    private BookingService bookingService;
    private PaymentGateway paymentGateway;
    private TicketCenter ticketCenter;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        paymentGateway = mock(PaymentGateway.class);
        ticketCenter = mock(TicketCenter.class);
        bookingService = new BookingService(paymentGateway, ticketCenter);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBookingSuccessWhenTicketCenterAllowsBooking() throws CannotChargeException {
        String johnDoe = "John Doe";
        Card amex = new Card("AMEX", 1000);
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(johnDoe);
        BookingResponse successBookingResponse = new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.SUCCESS, Optional.of(ticket));

        when(ticketCenter.canBook()).thenReturn(true);
        doNothing().when(paymentGateway).charge(eq(amex), eq(675.00));
        when(ticketCenter.book(eq(johnDoe))).thenReturn(ticket);

        BookingResponse bookingResponse = bookingService.bookTicket(johnDoe, amex, 675.00);

        assertEquals(successBookingResponse, bookingResponse);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnPaymentErrorWhenPaymentGatewayThrowsException() throws CannotChargeException {
        String johnDoe = "John Doe";
        Card visaCard = new Card("VISA", 1000);
        BookingResponse paymentErrorBookingResponse = new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.PAYMENT_ERROR, Optional.empty());

        when(ticketCenter.canBook()).thenReturn(true);
        doThrow(new CannotChargeException("low balance")).when(paymentGateway).charge(eq(visaCard), eq(500.00));

        BookingResponse actualBookingResponse = bookingService.bookTicket(johnDoe, visaCard, 500.00);

        assertEquals(paymentErrorBookingResponse, actualBookingResponse);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnSoldOutWhenTicketCenterCannotBook() throws CannotChargeException {
        String johnDoe = "John Doe";
        Card visaCard = new Card("VISA", 1000);
        BookingResponse soldOutBookingResponse = new BookingResponse(BookingStatus.SOLD_OUT, Optional.empty());

        when(ticketCenter.canBook()).thenReturn(false);

        BookingResponse bookingResponse = bookingService.bookTicket(johnDoe, visaCard, 500.00);

        assertEquals(soldOutBookingResponse, bookingResponse);
    }

}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would still like to see some fields `final`, like `ticklets` in `TicketCenter`. And `BookingResponse` could be a `record`.

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB, edited the title

Comment: The other thing that I could see adding is argument validation and the corresponding unit tests.  Most of your numbers shouldn't be negative.

Answer (score 2):

First: there's no evidence that you've set up a sane directory structure for your project, nor any package declarations. I hope that you do have package declarations, that your main files go in `src/main/java`, and your test files go in `src/test/java`.

I hope that you're using a modern JVM. That being the case, Mockito will not run unless you pass

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I have verified this on OpenJDK 17, `junit.jupiter` 5.5.2 and `mockito.core` 2.2.2.

My opinion is that `BookingResponse` should be a `record`. The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10) describes what this record keyword means and how it works. It mentions nothing of `record` only being appropriate for data access objects, and the behaviour fits: it implies full immutability and simple accessors. Some people want to deny this feature to all but data access object classes and will want you to write out the boilerplate `final` and getter declarations.

`BookingResponse.equals` should type-check and type-cast in one go with a pattern, as in

```
    if (!(obj instanceof BookingResponse otherBookingResponse))
        return false;
```

Similar `equals` pattern use for `Ticket`.

`Card.provider` should be `final`, as well as all of the fields of `TicketCenter`.

For `Card`, instead of subtracting from your `limit`, you could add to a `charge` and compare the charge to a final `limit`. This will capture more informative state, particularly for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think that BookingService should be a record? It's name already implies that it's a service instead of a data object so declaring it as a record would confuse anyone who comes across it. Record is not a generic shortcut for declaring immutable classes. It has a very specific semantic meaning and I think your suggestion abuses it.